# showing http images from html using webview

Tags: android

i want to show  the images from http not stored in local. am not able to show images.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    String customHtml = "<html><body>"
            + "<h1>Hello, WebView</h1>"
            +"<img src="+"'http://dreamatico.com/data_images/flowers/flowers-5.jpg'"+" height="+142+" width="+142+">"
            + "</body></html>";
    webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: have you provide internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Create the html file and put it in the assets folder and load that html file using

```
 WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html");
```

Comment: but i dont want to store images in asstes folder i want to load images from http link

Comment: no need to put the image in assets folder. u just have to put html file

Comment: i am creating app in which am getting data from api in the form of html.so every time its not possible to store in assets folder..so whats the solution